# Entity framework select specific columns from parent

Tags: entity-framework

```
public class parent {
    public int PID {get;set;}
    public String PName {get;set;}
    public int PAge {set;get;}
    public List<Child> children {get;set;}

}

public class child {
    public int CID {get;set;}
    public String CName {get;set;}
    public int CAge {set;get;}
    public parent pr{get;set;}

}
```

what I want is when i look for child by his ID I want to get the related object which is pr but I want to choose just PID and PAGE and finally return the query as object of type child, sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand, but I think you are looking for something like this

```
context.child.Where(c => c.CID == cid).Select(c => c.pr.PID);
```

This will only give you PID from the parent, you could select multiple columns

```
context.child.Where(c => c.CID == cid).Select(c => new {c.pr.PID, c.CID, c.CName, c.CAge});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Error 1 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: oops. i had things out of order a little bit, thank you probackpacker